# .ssh directory not being created

Tags: unix, ssh, cygwin

To generate the `.ssh` dir I use this command:

```
ssh-keygen
```

taken from this tutorial: http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/05%20-%20Setup%20SSHD.html

But the `.ssh` directory is not created so when I use `cd ~/.ssh` I get this error:

```
"no such file or directory"
```

Is there a step missing ? Should the `.ssh` dir be created when I use the `ssh-keygen` command?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I am assuming that you have enough permissions to create this directory.

To fix your problem, you can either ssh to some other location:

```
ssh user@some.host
```

and accept new key - it will create directory `~/.ssh` and `known_hosts` underneath, or simply create it manually using

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Note that `chmod 700` is an important step!

After that, ssh-keygen should work without complaints.

Comment: I'm inside chroot, and it can't (nor can I) create "/.ssh/" directory, I'd like to give the ssh command a different directory, in this case "/private/.ssh". I don't have `env`, and setting `set HOME=/private/` does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: The authorized keys should be chmod 600 or for me it doesn't work.

Comment: Who should own it? User and it's group?

Answer (score 16):

> Is there a step missing?

Yes. You need to create the directory:

```
mkdir ${HOME}/.ssh
```

Additionally, SSH requires you to set the permissions so that only you (the owner) can access anything in ~/.ssh:

```
% chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

> Should the `.ssh` dir be generated when I use the `ssh-keygen` command?

No. This command generates an SSH key pair but will fail if it cannot write to the required directory:

```
% ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa): /Users/tmp/does_not_exist
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
open /Users/tmp/does_not_exist failed: No such file or directory.
Saving the key failed: /Users/tmp/does_not_exist.
```

Once you've created your keys, you should also restrict who can read those key files to just yourself:

```
% chmod -R go-wrx ~/.ssh/*
```

Comment: You forgot to tell the reader to setup the permissions on .ssh

Comment: @Shrewmouse: Fixed

Comment: `chmod -R go-wrx` makes the assumption that the permissions of the dir has rwx set for the owner.  `chmod -R 700` is foolproof-ish.  Even if you fix that, In the end, your answer is a subset of the accepted answer.  You maybe should just remove your answer.

Comment: @Shrewmouse: I think that's a perfectly reasonable assumption on a freshly created directory. Who on earth would want `~/.ssh/id_rsa` to be _executable_?

Comment: ~/.ssh/id_rsa doesn't exist at this point in your workflow so your point is moot.  It's never a reasonable to assume when you can be explicit with less characters.  `chmod 700` trumps `chmod go-wrx` because it's explicit.  If you like to use 'rwx and 'ugo' then `chmod u+rwx ~/.ssh; chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh`

Answer (score 14):

As a slight improvement over the other answers, you can do the `mkdir` and `chmod` as a single operation using `mkdir`'s `-m` switch.

```
$ mkdir -m 700 ${HOME}/.ssh
```

#### Usage

From a Linux system

```
$ mkdir --help
Usage: mkdir [OPTION]... DIRECTORY...
Create the DIRECTORY(ies), if they do not already exist.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -m, --mode=MODE   set file mode (as in chmod), not a=rwx - umask
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to type command `ssh-keygen` and let it create the directory with default keys.