# Adding users to Google Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, debian, private-key, google-compute-engine

I have managed to set up my server with a default user 'admin'. The sshKeys in the metadata is set with the following format, described in the google documentation.

```
key: sshKeys 
value: admin:ssh-rsa XXXXXXXXXX
```

However, I am trying to add a new user to the system, hence I updated the metadata to the following

```
key: sshKeys 
value: admin:ssh-rsa XXXXXXXXXX newuser:ssh-rsa YYYYYYYYY
```

This has worked perfectly for me on one instance of server that I have set up sometime back. However I was unable to set it up on the new one. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add users to the system, I removed changed the `sshKeys` metadata back to the original one, comprising values for only one user:

```
key: sshKeys 
value: admin:ssh-rsa XXXXXXXXXX
```

Logged into the admin account, and added the new user using `useradd` command or whichever applicable to your own Linux distribution.

Under `/home/newuser`, I ran the following commands to create a new ssh folder (with reference from [.ssh directory not being created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190391/ssh-directory-not-being-created))

```
  mkdir ~/.ssh
  chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

After which, I manually updated the ssh keys in the authorized_keys file location at `/home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` and everything works perfectly!